# How to intercept a click on the "Up" (home button) Button in ActionBarSherlock?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-menu

I have implemented a search feature for one of my project using **ActionBar Sherlock**. So now I have the search edit text on the ActionBar like in the samples of the official AB sherlock project repo (on github) : [Collapsible action items](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/samples/demos/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/demos/CollapsibleActionItem.java)

My search edit text is filtering a ListView within the activity. When the user starts to type in some characters, the ListView gets filtered. I did it by adding a textWatcher to the search Edit text like this :

```
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

    menu.add(Menu.NONE, SEARCH_ACTION_MENU, 0, "Search")
        .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
        .setActionView(R.layout.search_edittext)
        .setShowAsAction(
            MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS
                | MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW);

    /** We get a reference to the search edit */
    MenuItemWrapper menuItemWrapper = (MenuItemWrapper) menu.getItem(0);
    final EditText searchEdit = (EditText) menuItemWrapper.getActionView();
    /** We add a listener search filter listener */
    searchEdit.addTextChangedListener(filterWatcher); // filterwatcher is a textWatcher
    return true;
  }
```

When I click on the search icon, the search Edit Text is shown and the user can start to type in things. Also, the home button is displayed as an "Up Home button" (with the left arrow).

Clicking on this arrow will make the search text view disappear but if the user has already started to type in things, the List View is filtered and is not reset when the search Text View is not visible anymore after the user clicks on the home "Up" button.

**My question is** : how can I intercept click on the **"Up"** button to reset my List View ? I think this is the only way I can reset my list.

I have already tried :

```
@Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case android.R.id.home:
        Log.d(Constants.LOG_TAG, "Home button clicked");
        return true;

      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }
```

It is not working when the "Home button" is displayed as "Up" button.

any help would be appreciated.

thanks in advance,

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand, but is it the physical android home button you wan to intercept?

Comment: @AndersMetnik I want to intercept the click on the "Up" button on the ActionBar (ActionBar Sherlock) not the physical one.

Please have a look at the bottom image of this link (the left-most button) :
http://developer.android.com/images/ui/actionbar-searchview.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement `CollapsibleActionView` on your view in order to receive the `onActionViewCollapsed()` callback.

You should also upgrade to the version of ActionBarSherlock that is on the `dev` branch since it has crucial fixes for collapsible action items when used on the native action bar.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it solved my issue. Actually, I implemented it like this : `menuItemWrapper.setOnActionExpandListener(new OnActionExpandListener() { // my logic here });` so in the `public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item)` method of the listener, I just added the code to reset my search filter. Again thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

It should work with `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Make sure you are using `com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem`.

You could also use `onMenuItemSelected(int featureId, MenuItem item)` in the same way.

Comment: I am using com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem but still the click on the "Up" button is now intercepted but if the button is in a "normal" mode (displayed as a simple icon without the left arrow) it's intercepted

Comment: is now or is **not** intercepted?